# AndroidX Navigation showing new NavigationGraph over BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, androidx, bottomnavigationview, android-navigation

I'm having trouble finding a clean solution to this problem:

I have a `mainActivity` containing a `BottomNavView` and a `NavController` that takes up all the space above the bottomNav with `navigation_main.xml` as graph.
On one of the bottomNav tabs i have a list of items, when the user selects the item, it should open i a new screen (i.e. bottomNavView, should not be visible anymore) displaying the info of the item, the model is supplied via `navigationArgs` with the model from the list.
I've created a new `navigation_details.xml` with the navigation setup for the details (Dialogs etc).

I came to two possible solutions, not a fan of either:

1. Open a new activity which only job is to contain the navController and host the new flow, which is then added as a navigation target in `navigation_main`. The only solution i found for passing the nav arguments to the fragment, is having the fragment try to pull it from it's own arguments, if it doesn't exist there, try the parent activity's `intent.extras`. This requires that the `argument:name=""` in the navigation[...].xml is that same for both the activity action and detailsFragment have the same key. This is in essence an issue on how to pass arguments to startDestination from when coming from another navigation graph.
2. Have the detailsFragment show up as a fullscreen dialog (Forcing all subsequent navigation to be fullscreen dialogs as well).

Anyone know of a way with a nicer and cleaner integration?
(Also, it's the first app i'm fully integrating Navigation Components, so my angle of attack might be off)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to pass argument from naveGrap to another navGrph use like this
    maybe this code will help you and if you need more help contact me..

if you show me your code maybe i could help you...

```
     NavDestination destinationFrom1;
     navHostFragment1.getNavController().addOnDestinationChangedListener((controller, 
     destination, arguments) -> {
        switch (destination.getId()) {


            case R.id.profileFragment:
                   destinationFrom1= destination;
                navigationListener.isHideBottomNavigation(false, destination.getId());
                break;
            default:
                navigationListener.isHideBottomNavigation(true, destination.getId());
                break;
        }
    });

      navHostFragment2.getNavController().addOnDestinationChangedListener((controller, 
        destination, arguments) -> {
        switch (destination.getId()) {


            case R.id.guidFragment:

                Map<String, NavArgument> arguments1 = destination.getArguments();
                  if(destinationFrom1!= null) {
                     destinationFrom1.addArgument("ssss",ANYARGUMENT);
                  }
                break;
            default:
                navigationListener.isHideBottomNavigation(true, destination.getId());
                break;
        }
    });
```